# Cannot open any apps except visual studio code

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, error-handling

I am currently on Ubuntu 20.04, but writing this from my phone.

I am unable to open the terminal, settings, ... I have been searching for hours, nothing worked.

Everytime I run an app, it loads but does not open. I am frustrated.

I tried installing all recommended packages and it did not work after rebooting.

Comment: Broken system? You have tried to install a different version of python?

Comment: yes actually I deleted python 2 from the system bwcause I though it was outdated. But after reinstlling it through the vscode terminal I feceive error after error

Comment: luckily I have the vscode terminal which is weridly the only app I can open

Comment: Leave system files alone if you do not want to break the system. Try whether reinstalling `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` restores all missing files.

Comment: Ok I somehow managed to install the sybaptic package, reload all apps and they all wor again... Except terminal.

Comment: E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code

--------- This is the error code I received from reloading everything in synapse.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide sufficient detail for other users to recreate your issue. As written the question itself does not provide any information about how you broke your system. Include information from comments as needed.

Comment: And very likely the fastest way to solve this issue is reinstalling Ubuntu. Then avoid doing the same mistake you did, i.e., leave system files alone.

Comment: Yes, all was useless, but thank you very much, I am reinstalling right now.